# Psycopg2 cannot be imported in Windows

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am working in **Windows 10** with **Python version 3.8.1** and Pycharm as IDE.

I am trying to upload a csv file to my local server in **PostgreSQL**. Since the data is big I intend of using **sqlalchemy** with create_engine.

So far so good, but when I run the code it shows the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

even thought I installed psycopg2 using the **pip command**.

When I try to import the psycopg2 package using Pycharm it tells me that

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

even thought I can see it is inside

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\

The following possible solutions that Pycharm suggest don't work:

- *Add pg_config to the PATH* because it **retrieves the same error**
- *Specify the full executable path with the option: python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build* because the terminal tells me that **python does not recognise setup.py as a file nor a directory**

I am bit lost since my original intention was to upload a csv file to a Postgres DB...

Comment: Do you have multiple python installations? Or, a virtual environment

Comment: Hi Rogan, thanks for your quick reply.
I do not fully know if multiple versions of python are install in my PC or if I am even using a Virtual Environment. How can I solve these doubts?

Comment: If you open `cmd` (not PowerShell), you can use `where pip` to show which installation of Python `pip` is using. Then you can see if that matches the installation that PyCharm is looking at

Comment: Just a wild guess: wondering if [psycopg2-binary](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) could be a solution.

Comment: @roganjosh I made  `where pip` and I got only one PATH:
`C:\Users\justy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe`




How can I check which `pip` is PyCharm looking for?

Comment: I'm not a PyCharm user, but I have hopefully given you enough info to track that down. Just search for how to do what you're asking me

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices, I have done so without much luck, but will continue searching!